# XCode 9.3 missing timeline slider

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

I installed Xcode 9.3 but I can't enable the playground Timeline slider. I know it is disabled by default; however, the option to enable it under the render documentation box in playground settings does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a normal project in Xcode and after drag the timeline slider to the playgrounds project